# is there $(document).find('selector') and $('selector') difference

Tags: jquery

I've  started  working on some project and in  code I  find combintions  of $(document).find('selector') and  $('selector'). I  cant  find any  real  reason why this is done. I  there any  significant  differnece between  those two so that  they are  used simultaneously in project? should I prefer one before another in some cases?

Comment: using the selector you directly access the elements you want, using find() you search the dom finding the elements which will take longer

Comment: @VDesign using `$('div')` still requires to search in whole DOM, doesn't it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$(document).find("selector")` and `$("selector")` will match the same set of elements.

There's no reason to use `$(document).find("selector")` over just `$("selector")` (**unless** the selector you're using comes from an untrusted source — more on that in a moment), and several reasons not to:

1. It's longer to write and more awkward to read, inflating your script size
2. It results in more memory churn (more temporary objects get created/destroyed)
3. It's slower - http://jsperf.com/vs-document-find, http://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again

[image]

However, if you have `$(selector)` where `selector` comes from an untrusted source, beware that jQuery sniffs the string and *either* does a selection *or* creates new HTML elements. That is, `$("div")` looks for `div`s but `$("<div>")` *creates* a div. If the text you're using comes from an untrusted source, it could be `<script src='http://example.com/path/to/malicious/script.js>`. Now, in and of itself that wouldn't be a problem, but if the resulting `script` element is added to a document (for instance, `$(selector).appendTo(document.body)`), suddenly it's an [XSS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vector. Likely? No, if you're *selecting* you aren't that likely to then append (though you might, if you're moving elements). But if the selector comes from an untrusted source, `$(document).find(selector)` ensures that the text is **only** used as a selector, not as an HTML string. Or, on a modern browser, `$(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` (but you can't use jQuery's extensions to selectors that way).

Comment: 1. Without any doubts. 2. Was it stated somewhere or can it be tested somehow? It sounds logical, but nevertheless... 3. For IDs it is expected result, but for base selector I don't see big difference (well, selector wins there too, yes).

Comment: @Regent: Re 2: `$(document)` allocates and returns an object, then `.find("selector")` allocates and returns a *new* object.

Comment: Looking at the following code, they don't seem equivalent, as far as some kind of XSS attack is concerned: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/29f9237f735b90dbc89e003db0c62dec2db0b308

Comment: @DavidA. - Very good point. While I just said they'd match the same elements, not that they were equivalent, I also said "There's no reason to use `$(document).find(...)` instead of..." which is incorrect if the selector comes from an untrusted source -- I've fixed that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

The Main Difference Is That When You Are Dynamically Generate Something like div textbox and things like that your real DOM doesn't know about this so if you are write $('selector') it will not affect or didn't find anything . in that situation you need to specified to javascript  that i am Adding something so please check this selector in all dom , so using

```
$(document).find("selector")
```

will find element in your all over dom.

Answer (score 3):

They're functionally equivalent. There is no difference in behavior between `$("selector")`, `$(document).find("selector")` and `$("selector", document)`.

As for performance, some of the variants may be slightly slower than the others (since these methods are implemented in terms of the others). This is, however, an implementation detail and is subject to change between releases. Benchmarking a specific release would tell for sure.

Comment: Gratuitous perf: http://jsperf.com/vs-document-find `$(document).find(...)` also results in more memory churn (as does `$("selector", context)` as all that happens is jQuery converts it to `$(context).find("selector")`).

Answer (score 2):

`$(document).find(selector)` and `$(selector)` both are searching the selector in the document.

Answer (score 2):

Exact answer to the question is 'yes there is difference between both' even though both do the same job of pointing / selecting the element.

When document is loaded, jQuery scope gets defined. Thus usually $('selector') is used to point the element.

But what if elements are added after this scope is defined. I.e. If elements are loaded through ajax call. jQuery can't find these elements. Thus to point to such elements we use alternative function $('scope').find('selector').

Best-practice: if you don't add elements after document is loaded. Don't use "$('scope').find('selector')" method. As the given name will be considered as criteria and according to the find function, every element will be checked to match the criteria which will consume more time and will demand more resource than directly pointing method.

Comment: *"But what if elements are added after this scope is defined. I.e. If elements are loaded through ajax call. jQuery can't find these elements."* This is simply wrong. jQuery queries the DOM as it is when you make the call. It has no trouble whatsoever finding elements added dynamically, with `$(selector)`: http://jsfiddle.net/3kdmw5hf/

Comment: if its not coming from jquery but the internal js functions which create the dom elements on the fly? For example kendo observables?